# Received incoming SIP connection from unknown peer

Tags: asterisk

I have created 2 users in sip_additional.config. which is like:

```
[james]
secret=12345
context=tenancy1
host=dynamic
type=friend
allow=ulaw,alaw

[caleb]
secret=12345
context=tenancy1
host=dynamic
type=friend
allow=ulaw,alaw
```

And created dialplan for above context. Here I am assigning duplicate extensions but with different context ie. 2222,2225 is already assigned to another users but with different context (from-internal).

```
[tenancy1]
exten => 2222,1,NoOp(james calling)
same => n,Dial(SIP/james)
same => n,Hangup

exten => 2225,1,NoOp(caleb calling)
same => n,Dial(SIP/caleb)
same => n,Hangup
```

The issue here is, when i make call from 2222 to 2225 then 2224 is ringing but 2225 is unable to make a call. I traced from CLI, it is saying

```
 -- Executing [2222@from-sip-external:1] NoOp("SIP/caleb-00000004", "Received incoming SIP connection from unknown peer to 2222") in new stack
-- Executing [2222@from-sip-external:2] Set("SIP/caleb-00000004", "DID=2222") in new stack
-- Executing [2222@from-sip-external:3] Goto("SIP/caleb-00000004", "s,1") in new stack
-- Goto (from-sip-external,s,1)
-- Executing [s@from-sip-external:1] GotoIf("SIP/caleb-00000004", "0?checklang:noanonymous") in new stack
-- Goto (from-sip-external,s,5)
-- Executing [s@from-sip-external:5] Set("SIP/caleb-00000004", "TIMEOUT(absolute)=15") in new stack
-- Channel will hangup at 2017-07-07 07:59:00.448 EDT.
-- Executing [s@from-sip-external:6] Log("SIP/caleb-00000004", "WARNING,"Rejecting unknown SIP connection from 172.16.9.112"") in new stack
[2017-07-07 07:58:45] WARNING[5606][C-00000003]: Ext. s:6 @ from-sip-external: "Rejecting unknown SIP connection from 172.16.9.112"
-- Executing [s@from-sip-external:7] Answer("SIP/caleb-00000004", "") in new stack
[2017-07-07 07:58:45] NOTICE[5606][C-00000003]: res_rtp_asterisk.c:4365 ast_rtp_read: Unknown RTP codec 95 received from '172.16.9.112:8000'
-- Executing [s@from-sip-external:8] Wait("SIP/caleb-00000004", "2") in new stack
-- Executing [s@from-sip-external:9] Playback("SIP/caleb-00000004", "ss-noservice") in new stack
-- <SIP/caleb-00000004> Playing 'ss-noservice.ulaw' (language 'en')
-- Executing [s@from-sip-external:10] PlayTones("SIP/caleb-00000004", "congestion") in new stack
-- Executing [s@from-sip-external:11] Congestion("SIP/caleb-00000004", "5") in new stack
```

Do anyone have any idea about this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Acordinly to your trace you are using freepxb web.

So if you are using it, it is nice idea add number at your web in incoming section.

"Unknown peer" mean asterisk not matched incoming request with your sip sections. For more info enable debug and check what exactly asterisk see.